# How to convert datetime to epoch time in milliseconds javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I convert "2016-03-08T14:47:39.231Z" to time in epoch milliseconds that I can use in highcharts?

Comment: new Date("2016-03-08T14:47:39.231Z").getTime() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, [note 1] not counting leap seconds

All you have to go is `date.getTime()/1000`. `date.getTime()` or `+date` will return value in milliseconds.

**Note:** as correctly pointed out by [@Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5929690/rahul-sharma), you do not have to divide by 1000 as highchart create date out of it. Just use `date.getTime()` or `+date`

> Highcharts doesn't accept seconds when the xAxis type is set to datetime.

**Pure JS**

```js
var d = new Date(" 5/13/2016, 5:27:26 PM GMT+5:30");
console.log(d.getTime())
```

Comment: Th eproblem is that It does not give the right value for highcharts. I stil see wrong dates.

Comment: @Imo then you have an entirely different question to ask :)

Comment: doesn't `getTime` return milliseconds? if it returns milliseconds and you need milliseconds, why do you have to divide by 1000?

Comment: UNIX time is defined as the time (can be hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) elapsed since 00:00:00 but that doesn't imply that getTime method returns seconds. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) is the documentation, check the return value.

Comment: The question is related to highcharts. Highcharts doesn't accept seconds when the xAxis type is set to datetime. "time in epoch milliseconds that I can use in highcharts" is mentioned in the question, converting the value returned from getTime to seconds just creates confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution to get the Unix timestamp of any JavaScript Date object.

```
// Copy & Paste this
 Date.prototype.getUnixTime = function() { return this.getTime()/1000|0 };
 if(!Date.now) Date.now = function() { return new Date(); }
 Date.time = function() { return Date.now().getUnixTime(); }

// Get the current time as Unix time
 var currentUnixTime = Date.time();
 currentUnixTime = Date.now().getUnixTime(); // same as above

// Parse a date and get it as Unix time
 var parsedUnixTime = new Date('Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT').getUnixTime();
// parsedUnixTime==819898200
```

Ref: [Link,coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/rbfl6g/how-to-get-the-correct-unix-timestamp-from-any-date-in-javascript)